# Isolar domínio da camada de apresentação

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, arquitetura-de-software, automapper

A boa prática de arquitetura de software diz que a camada de apresentação não 
deve conhecer a camada de domínio.
Estou tentando fazer esse isolamento entre essas camadas, porém o
que está dificultando essa separação é o framework de mapeamento
de objetos, o AutoMapper.

Estou com o seguinte cenário:

Camada Presentation > Camada Application > Camada Domain

Na camada Domain tenho a entidade Cliente.
Na camada Presentation tenho o ClienteViewModel.

Para fazer o mapeamento dessas classes, utilizo o
AutoMapper. O problema é que sua configuração é feita
na camada Presentation, e dessa forma acaba que essa camada tenha
que conhecer o domínio.

```
//Método da classe DomainToViewModelMappingProfile que está na Presentation
protected override void Configure()
{
    // Faz referência ao Cliente do domínio.
    Mapper.CreateMap<Cliente, ClienteViewModel>();
}

// Métodos da classe ClienteMapper
public static ClienteViewModel MapearClienteParaClienteViewModel(Cliente cliente)
{
    return Mapper.Map<Cliente, ClienteViewModel>(cliente);
}

public static Cliente MapearClienteViewModelParaCliente(ClienteViewModel clienteView)
{
    return Mapper.Map<ClienteViewModel, Cliente>(clienteView);
}
```

Tentei jogar o AutoMapper na camada Application, mas como
ela referencia o domínio não da para referenciar a Presentation,
pois ocorre problema de depedência circular.

Qual seria o melhor caminho para fazer esse isolamento?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Eu usaria interfaces para injeção de dependência, e mais uma camada de crosscutting para mapear através dos projetos as classes necessárias com suas interfaces.

Nesse projeto no github do ***Eduardo Pires*** contem um projeto desenvolvido com boas praticas e Design Patterns entre outros padrões de projeto. Inclusive ele usa o automapper...

> [Equinox](https://github.com/EduardoPires/EquinoxProject)
>
> O objetivo deste projeto é implementar as tecnologias usadas mais
>   comuns e compartilhar com a comunidade técnica a melhor maneira de
>   desenvolver ótimos aplicativos com o .NET.

Comment: Obrigado Nicolas! Mas ao fazer o download alguns projetos não carregam.

Comment: Os projetos Equinox.UI.Site e o Equinox.WebApi apresentam a falha de carregamento: o SDK 'Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web' especificado não pôde ser encontrado.

Comment: Então cara esse projeto se mantem em Dot.Net Core, que possui o SDK no visual studio 2017, então se tentar carregar com visual studio 2015 para baixo eles não possuem o compatibilidade. uma opção e carregar com o visual code. [Visual Code](https://code.visualstudio.com/download)